# After implementing text watcher I am getting only first Character of the String in textview?

Tags: android, textwatcher

I have this string:

```
String sentence = sometext __ sometext __ sometext __ sometext.("__" = underscore)
```

So in place of the underscores, I want to put the EditText values of what the user inputs in real time. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


    sentence = tv.getText().toString(); //gettingthestring.

    edtv1 = ed1.getText().toString();
    edtv2 = ed2.getText().toString();
    edtv3 = ed3.getText().toString();

    callMethod();


}


private void callMethod() {


    if (ed1 != null) {
        ed1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
               sen1 =(sentence.replaceFirst("__", "___" ));

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                tv.setText(sen1.replace("___" ,"_"+s.toString()+"_"));

            }
        });
        edtv1 = ed1.getText().toString();

    }
    callMethod2();
}

private void callMethod2() {


    if (ed2 != null) {


        ed2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


                sen2 = tv.getText().toString(); //got the new string
      //sen = sometext _ed1 value_ sometext __ sometext __ sometext.("__" = underscore)

                sen2 =(sen2.replaceFirst("__","___" ));

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                tv.setText(sen2.replace("___","_"+s.toString()+"_"));

            }
        });
        edtv2 = ed2.getText().toString();

        sen2 = sentence;



    }
    callMethod3();

 //some code

   }
```

**The Problem:**

For the second and third "__"(underscores) I am seeing only the first character of the string irrespective of how many characters the user inputs.

Comment: Read documentation : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html. TextWatcher will be called after each character change in your `EditText` so it is default behaviour..!!

Answer (score 0):

In the `afterTextChanged()`, just save the updated sentence in a string and use that string for the next `afterTextChanged()`.

```
String update1 = txtview.getText().toString();
```

Comment: That is not "one line". They are quite a lot. :|

Comment: String update1 = (String) txtview.getText(); //I saved my updated string in update1 and used this for the second method

Comment: It would be nice if you update your answer with relevant code and comments and remove things which aren't important/necessary. :)